# swift Перерисовка view в tableview

Tags: swift

Создал кастомный `view`

```
override func draw(_ rect: CGRect)
    {
        let arrowPath = UIBezierPath()
        arrowPath.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0))
        arrowPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.width - 30, y: 0))
        arrowPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.width, y: 30))
        arrowPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.width, y: rect.height))
        arrowPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: rect.height))
        arrowPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0))
        arrowPath.close()
        ColorsConst.yellow.set()
        arrowPath.fill()
    }
```

эта вьюшка стоит у меня в tableview, проблема в том, что отображается криво

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

хотя я в функции `draw` четко указываю размер линии. Скорее всего, это происходит из за того, что высота `tableview` плавающая `UITableView.automaticDimension`, если поставить строгую высоту ячейки, то таких проблем нет. Можно ли оставить динамическую высоту и решить проблему отображения?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Скорее всего такой эффект возникает из-за повторного использования ячеек в таблице при скроллинге таблицы, поэтому вьюшки нужно принудительно перерисовывать. Попробуйте нечто подобное

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! TestTableViewCell
        // ...
        cell.customView.setNeedsDisplay()
        return cell
    }
```

Comment: спасибо большое